# Convert factors to datetime, <fctr> 10/25/2018 (M, D, Y)

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data frame called RequisitionHistory2 with a variable called RequisitionDateTime and the levels are factors which look like  `4/30/2019 14:16` I would like to split this into RequisitionDate and RequisitionTime in a datetime format.

I tried this code, but this still does not solve my issue with needing to split these into their own columns. The code also did not work as I got the error below.

```
mutate(When = as.POSIXct(RequisitionHistory2, format="%m/%d/%. %H:%M %p"))

Error in as.POSIXct.default(RequisitionHistory2, format = "%m/%d/%. %H:%M %p") : do not know how to convert 'RequisitionHistory2' to class “POSIXct”
```

I would like to have the variable RequisitionDateTime split into RequisitionDate and another variable RequisitionTime in the dataframe RequisitionHistory2. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert factors to datetime directly.  You will need to convert it to a character first and then use a datetime function.

```
as.Date(as.character("10/25/2018"), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

would work for your `date` example.

```
library(lubridate)
mutate(df,When = mdy_hm(RequisitionHistory2))
```

If your datetime is in `4/30/2019 14:16` format

Note that `as.POSIXct()` works only on datetimes already in ISO 8601 format.  I wrote a blog post about this and I think would be helpful for you to check out:
https://jackylam.io/tutorial/uber-data/

Answer (score 0):

The [anytime](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/index.html) package ON CRAN *directly* converts from *many formats*, including `factor` and `ordered` to dates and datetime objects.  It also heuristically tries a number of viable formats so that you do not need a format string.  See the [README at GitHub](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime) for an introduction, there is also a [vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/vignettes/anytime-introduction.pdf)

Your example works:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anytime(as.factor("4/30/2019 14:16"))
[1] "2019-04-30 14:16:00 CDT"
R> anytime(as.factor("4/3/2019 14:16:17"), useR=TRUE)
[1] "2019-04-03 14:16:17 CDT"
R>
```

However, the underlying (Boost C++) parser does not like single digit days or month so you may need to flip back to R's parser via `useR=TRUE` as I did on the second example.